# Change where I installed Cmake initially to usr/local/bin on mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, installation

I am new to the computer and as I wanted to install Cmake instead of installing it in usr/bin or usr/local/bin I installed it in Users/Admin/Source!
Could you help me to figure out how can I change its directory or do I have to uninstall it completely?!

To install Cmake I followed the steps here http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/cmake/, except the first line.

Thanks

Comment: By "first line" you mean you were in a different directory when you downloaded cmake ? something like "cd .../Users/Admin/Source" ?

Comment: yes, right I did cd /Users/Admin/Source instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you successfully went through the steps in the link you provided, cmake is now installed in /usr/local/cmake/bin.
(From what I understand you just did the download in another directory which is fine).

Since the tutorial also tells you to add this directory to your PATH it should be fine. i.e cmake should be accessible from anywhere after sourcing again your .bash_profile or simply opening a new terminal.

If for any other reason you need cmake to be in /usr/local/bin. you can create a symbolic link in this directory:

```
ln -s /usr/local/cmake/bin/cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake
```

Comment: I need to change my Cmake compiler from clang to g++, but as I try `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++`  I get that the source directory /usr/local/cmake does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. and I thought it might be because of the little arrow on the cmake folder when I look it up in the finder in /usr/local